# How to get fetch data when you click on a marker and display in a div outside of the map

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In this code I want the user to click on a marker on the map and when they click on the marker they get back the reviews of that specific place .At the moment what I have working is that it get's the nearby cafes in the location that you are located,puts markers on each cafe and it retrieves back reviews from one cafe only without you selecting which cafe you want .I know you have to use onClickEventListener but I'm finding it hard to understand how it will work all together ,I have searched online for a solution and in the Developers website but I can't anything as similar as what I'm trying to do.

This is my script.js file :

```
var map,service ;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        geoLocationInit();
        var myLatLng= new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8665433,151.1956316);




        function  geoLocationInit(){

            if(navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, fail);
            }else{
                alert("Browser not supported");
            }
        }
        function  success(position) {
            console.log(position);
            var latval=position.coords.latitude;
            var Ingval=position.coords.longitude;

            myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(latval,Ingval);
            createMap(myLatLng);

        }
        function fail(){
            alert("it fails");
        }



        function createMap(myLatLng,type){
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                center: myLatLng,
                scrollwheel: false,
                zoom: 12
            });

            var marker= new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatLng,
                map: map
            })

            function createMarker(latlng,icn,name){

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latlng,
                map: map,
                icon:icn,
                title: name
            });
        }

        var request = {
            location: myLatLng,
            radius: '2500',

            types: ['cafe']
        };

        service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
        service.nearbySearch(request, callback);



            function callback(results,status) {

            if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    var place = results[i];
                    console.log(place);
                    latlng= place.geometry.location;
                    name= place.name;
                    icn ='https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png';

                    createMarker(latlng,icn,name);


                    service.getDetails({placeId: place.place_id}, function(place, status) {
                        if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                            let reviewEl = document.querySelector('.reviews');
                            for (let review of place.reviews){
                                let li = document.createElement('li');
                                li.innerHTML = `<div>Name of Place: ${name}</div>
                               <div>Author: ${review.author_name}</div>
                               <em>${review.text}</em>
                               <div>Rating: ${review.rating} star(s)</div>`;

                                reviewEl.appendChild(li);
                            }
                        }})
                }



            }}}});
```

This is my front.blade.php class:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

    @section('content')

        <div class="container">

          <div id="map">
          </div>
            <ul class="reviews"></ul>

        </div>

    @endsection
```

And this my main.css file:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#map {
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
}

.reviews {
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
}

.reviews li+li {
    margin-top: 1em;
    padding-top: 1em;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}
.reviews em{display:block;margin:0.3em 0;}
```

Below is a screenshot of what I have .So just a reminder of what is happening ,basically it is getting the local cafes nearby your location ,putting a marker on each one and it's only giving back the reviews of one cafe without you selecting which cafe's reviews you want.I want the user to click on the marker of the cafe and give back reviews of the selected cafe .
[image]

Comment: What happens with your code right now?  Once you have the reviews you should be able to insert them in a div.

Comment: The reviews of one cafe come back on a div .I want the user to select the cafe (selecting would be clicking on one of the markers) that they want to see the reviews in . The problem at the moment is that the user cannot select which cafe they want to see the reviews .

Comment: you are really asking about a UI question then, not how to get data from a web service?

Comment: Well I want fetch the right data ,what the user wants ,so I'm trying to retrieve data except in better way